# Price Filter not displaying in Magento 1.9.2.4 Community Edition

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, layered-navigation, ce-1.9.2.4, magento-1.9.2.0

Hope all of you are doing good.

Guys I have followed 2 tutorials to do this task but in default magento without any customization simply it is not coming.

http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-configure-the-price-filter-for-layered-navigation.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713009/price-ranges-in-magento

I am sharing my setting of **system -> configuration -> catalog -> layered navigation**

[image]
Here is my price attribute settings : 
[image]

[image]

This is my frontend display:

[image]

One more thing when I am setting **Use In Search Results Layered Navigation as yes** under price attribute setting price filter is visible on search result. 
see the screen shot.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that **Is Anchor** is set to **Yes** for the categories where you want to display the layered navigation. You can edit this for each category under the **Display Settings** tab in admin.

The layered navigation block is included in the layout only for the `catalog_category_layered` handle:

```
<catalog_category_layered translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Category (Anchor)</label>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

and this handle is loaded only for the categories that have **Is Anchor** is set to **Yes**.

Answer (score 1):

Set `Is Anchor` to `Yes` for `Category 1`.You can set this via following steps

Go to `Manage Categories`
    - Select `Category 1` from left
    - Select `Display Settings` tab from right and set `Is Anchor` to `Yes` here.

and Save Category and clear cache and check.